# If a two-dimensional distribution function $F$ has continuous density $f$ then $f(x,y)=\frac{\partial^2F(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

(Excercise 20.3, P. Billingsley, Probability and measure) Suppose two-dimensional distribution function $F$ has continuous density $f$. Show that 
$$f(x,y)=\frac{\partial^2F(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y}.$$

This is incorrect! For example, the density
$$ f(x,y)= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}} |x| \exp\left(-|x|-\frac{1}{2}x̣^2y^2\right)$$
it does not verify the affirmation.

Under what conditions this relation between $F$ and $f$ is valid?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: My question is to establish sufficient conditions.